# How would I auto fill a field in a point feature based off of a polygon that it is within?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade, arcgis-field-maps

I am creating a field map for data collection in which we have a polygon layer and a point layer. we will be creating points and every point will be within one of these polygons, I was wondering if it was possible to pull the name field of the polygon layer and fill a corresponding field automatically on the point layer when the point is generated based off of the location of the point using arcade functions in the new field maps designer.

Comment: [Intersects()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#intersects)?

Comment: Either use attribute expressions, or use the field maps url messages to create a custom rich text button in the polygon attribute data...